# Background scrolls while content is fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am making a website using vue.js and Bootstrap I have made use of bootstrap's `jumbotron` component at the top of my web page right below my navigation and I would like to know how to make some of the elements scrollable while keeping some elements stationary. I will include an example as I am aware this is still confusing at this  point.

**Demo**

[This is a demo of just the jumbotron](https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-cerf-70qwh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) there will be other content on the page beside the jumbotron what I want is the Buick logo (I will have other logos as well) to scroll for a short time in the background behind the other content until the main scroll action of the page takes over. I hope what I am looking for is clear now. If you need more info I will be happy to provide it.

[image: This is to help demonstrate my problem]

[image: This is another image]

Just to be clear in these pictures just show the jumbotron not the whole page. Also fixed position is not a solution to my problem as I want the stationary elements to remain in the jumbotron.

Comment: At least to me it is not very clear yet what exactly you want to accomplish. Maybe you can make a quick drawing in e.g. paint of the starting state, the intermediate state and the end state and explain what should happen and add those to the question.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I added some pictures let me know if this helps you understand what I am trying to achieve

Comment: So you want some text to remain in a fixed position on the screen, until the jumbotron leaves the screen, at which point the fixed text should scroll off the screen with the jumbotron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get the problem right, this should do the trick: https://codesandbox.io/embed/serene-rhodes-42224?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark.

Briefly what was done:

1. Make text and logo wrappers direct children of scrolling container. In your case it was .jumbotron, which had only one direct child - native jumbotron .container. So, instead I set the scrolling behavior on .wrapper div instead of .jumbotron.
2. Set position sticky on text wrapper. This will give us the desired behavior: sticks to the top (or any set border) of parent, and scrolls with it when main window scrolls.
3. Set a height for logo wrapper with position absolute, which basically controls how long the user will have to scroll the jumbotron before the logo appears.

Comment: Thank you for understanding what I wanted. Let me just integrate it into my website and I will accept your answer momentarily.

Comment: Just one quick question I've been playing with the height properties and I can't get the logo to scroll back off the top of the jumbotron which is what I want

Comment: If you are talking about the following events: scroll up -> logo to top -> keep scrolling -> main window scroll up -> scroll down -> main window scroll down -> keep scrolling -> logo not moving down, then it is linked to jumbotron container not regaining the focus after the main window finished scrolling. It works though if you move the cursor at least   some pixels, and try scrolling again. I do not know if this is expected behaviour with nested scrolling or not. If it is not what you mean, please explain a little more.

Comment: The issue is that the logo never reaches the top of the jumbotron it stops about halfway I understand the concept of the focus needing to be on the jumbotron in order to control the scroll of the logo this is not the issue.

Comment: ok. Then you should set a fixed height for parent container (`.wrapper`), and set the `bottom` property of moving element (`.alpha`) to the difference between the wrapper height and the element's height (I have updated the codesandbox). Also, take notice that jumbotron has a native top and bottom padding of 64px, so the logo will not scroll above that point.

Comment: Thank you very Much!

Answer (score -2):

So from what I understand you want to make some elements scrollable whilst others are in fixed positions. this can be done using css positioning and overflow.
If you have an element that you want to be unscrollable unless there is enough content in that div to make it scrollable use the following css

```css
position: fixed;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

However if you want the element to remain unscrollable (you cant scroll on it no matter what) just use the following css:

```css
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: okay fixed is not what i want If I use fixed. It will fix those elements to the entire page I want them to remain in the ``jumbotron`` I'm sorry i thought this was clear from my example. Can you explain how I would use ``overflow: hidden;`` with my demo

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `background-attachment` property of CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fixed">
--- Your Content Here ---
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fixed {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/11/23/22/soap-bubbles-1451092_960_720.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 32px auto;
}
```

**[Check CodePen here](https://codepen.io/vibhordube/pen/eYJPJqG?editors=1100)**

Comment: Can you explain alittle more how I would use this property given my use case I am going to have muiltiple small images I want to scroll in the background

Comment: Sorry if this sounds rude, did you check the code snippet or Codepen? Have you tried integrating the styling from this answer to your code? Firstly, you have to move your image to the `background-img` property of CSS from the current implementation of `<img>`. At least give it a try and post the query of what you don't understand. This answer is minimal and pretty straightforward. If you still don't get it, come up with specific doubts.

Comment: Yes i have tried this with my webpage I was confused at first because your codepen does not appear to be what I am looking for this property seems to be fixing the image and allowing the text to scroll I want the opposite.

Comment: Can you share some example where you've seen such an effect. I'm sorry, I'm not able to imagine what you are talking about. Have you tried looking for the `Parallax` effect? Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Okay [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-smoke-i1tr4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is an example of what I am talking about and if I understand the Parllax effect correctly it is when elements on the screen have different scroll rates what I want is the text in the jumbotron to be fixed and the logos to move behind the text as the user scrolls